# Using Codable parse Nested JSON like ObjectMapper Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable

I have a JSON string, I want to parse it like ObjectMapper Using Codable Protocol.

```
    struct Health: Mappable {
    var size: [String : Any] = [:]?
    var name: Double?

    init?(map: Map) {

    }

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        size    <- map["health.size"]
        name    <- map["health.name"]
    }
}
```

I want to eliminate Health struct model with direct access, as creating each model struct for different properties.

```
let jsonString = """
 {
    "health": {
        "size":{
            "width":150,
            "height":150
            },
        "name":"Apple"
        }
 }
 """
```

I want to access properties with (.) Dot operator like health.size without creating Struct Model for Health.

```
struct HealthType: Codable {
    var health: Health
 }

struct Health: Codable {
        var title: String
        var size: Size

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey
        {
            case title = "name"
        }
     }

     struct Size: Codable {
        var width: Double
        var height: Double
     }
```

Comment: `ObjectMapper` is much more readable and can handle null key for dev, also auto map to enum type. It's much more useful than `Codable`. IMO :)

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you need to implement the `Codable` protocol yourself. It's not too difficult:

Try the following on Playground.

```
import Foundation

struct HealthType: Codable {
    let title: String
    let width: Double
    let height: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey
    {
        case health = "health"
        case title = "name"
        case width = "width"
        case height = "height"
        case size = "size"
    }
}

extension HealthType {

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let healthTypeContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let health = try healthTypeContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .health)
        let size = try health.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .size)
        let title = try health.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        let width = try size.decode(Double.self, forKey: .width)
        let height = try size.decode(Double.self, forKey: .height)
        self.init(title: title, width: width, height: height)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        var health = container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .health)
        var size = health.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .size)
        try health.encode(title, forKey: .title)
        try size.encode(width, forKey: .width)
        try size.encode(height, forKey: .height)
    }
}

let jsonData = """
{
"health": {
    "size":{
        "width":150,
        "height":150
    },
    "name":"Apple"
}
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
do {
    print(jsonData)
    let healthType = try JSONDecoder().decode(HealthType.self, from: jsonData)
    print(healthType.title)  // Apple
    print(healthType.width)  // 150.0
    print(healthType.width)  // 150.0
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: here you are not using size. So how can i access by property like example size.height or size.width

Answer (score 0):

You can almost make this work. However, `JSONDecoder` operates on `Data` instead of `String`, a Playground is encoded using UTF-8 by default so the following Playground will run:

```
import Cocoa

let jsonData = """
    {
        "health": {
            "size":{
                "width":150,
                "height":150
           },
           "name":"Apple"
        }
    }
    """.data(using: .utf8)!

struct HealthType: Codable {
    var health: Health
}

struct Health: Codable {
    var title: String
    var size: Size

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey
    {
        case title = "name"
        case size
    }
}

struct Size: Codable {
    var width: Double
    var height: Double
}

do {
    let health = try JSONDecoder().decode(HealthType.self, from:jsonData)
    print(health)
    let h = health.health
    print(h.title)

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

While this parses and runs well I cannot make sense of your statement "without creating Struct Model for Health". Part of the tradeoff of using `Codable` is that you will have to provide structure definitions of the relevant part of your JSON. You can also parse your input into `[String:Any].self`, but working with it is a drag. You will have to constantly evaluate casts and optionals. When using the `Codable` protocol for parsing your errors will all be concentrated into the things `decode` may `throw` at you. The info you get concerning is fairly good at describing the faults in your JSON (or your `struct` depending on your point of view).

To cut a long story short: As long as your JSON contains your `"health"` key you will have to tell it what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is ***not expose the properties that I don't need*** then one way is to privately decode the whole structure and then make only those properties available that you are going to expose in the outer world.

```
struct Health {
    let size: Size
    let title: String

    struct Size: Decodable {
        let width: Int
        let height: Int
    }
    private struct RawResponse: Decodable {
        let health: PrivateHealth
        struct PrivateHealth: Decodable {
            let size: Size
            let name: String
        }
    }
}

// Decodable requirement is moved to extension so that default initializer is accessible
extension Health: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let response = try RawResponse(from: decoder)
        size = response.health.size
        title = response.health.name
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let jsonData = """
{
    "health": {
        "size":{
            "width":150,
            "height":150
        },
        "name":"Apple"
    }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let health = try JSONDecoder().decode(Health.self, from: jsonData)
    print(health.size)  // Size(width: 150, height: 150)
    print(health.title)  // Apple
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

---

### Edit: if you need the encoding feature also

If you also need to implement the `Encodable` protocol so that you can encode your data like the actual response then you can do it with:

```
extension Health: Encodable {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        let health = Health.RawResponse.PrivateHealth(size: size, name: title)
        let response = RawResponse(health: health)
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(response)
    }
}
```

> For this to work, you will need to make your `RawResponse`, `PrivateHealth` and `Size` struct to be Encodable too

- Change to **`private struct RawResponse: Encodable, Decodable {`**
- Change to **`struct PrivateHealth: Encodable, Decodable {`**
- Change to **`struct Size: Encodable, Decodable {`**

**Example of encoding:**

```
let health = Health(size: Health.Size(width: 150, height: 150), title: "Apple")
do {
    let encodedHealth = try JSONEncoder().encode(health)  // Encoded data
    // For checking purpose, you convert the data to string and print
    let jsonString = String(data: encodedHealth, encoding: .utf8)!
    print(jsonString)  // This will ensure data is encoded as your desired format
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: @Nayeem here you are creating struct model for nested JSON, for this i want to access directly with property name.

Comment: What do you actually mean by ___directly with property name___? I don't get it.

Comment: like size.width or size.height of nested JSON.

Comment: You can with `health.size.width`

Answer (score 0):

Hey I created [KeyedCodable](https://github.com/dgrzeszczak/KeyedCodable) and I think it is exactly what you are looking for. Your implementation will look like this.

```
struct Health: Codable, Keyedable {
    var size: [String: Int]!
    var name: String?

    mutating func map(map: KeyMap) throws {
        try size <-> map["health.size"]
        try name <-> map["health.name"]
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        try KeyedDecoder(with: decoder).decode(to: &self)
    }
}
```

Comment: ya I need same. But here again I need to add this support KeyedCodable.